# Removing white background from linked images

Tags: css

My first epub looks fine when viewed in iBooks, but it has a problem in Kindle.

Hyperlinked home page icons have a white background. So a triangular image just looks like a big white square.

I added this to my style sheet:

```
a { background: none; }
```

But that doesn't work.

Ideally, I'd like all my linked images to have neither a background color nor an underline.

Comment: Which format are you using for these images?

Comment: Are you using transparent .png images, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, they're png's with transparent backgrounds. In the meantime, I may have answered my own question. Instead of a { background: none; } I should have entered a:link { background: none; } I haven't tested it in a finished epub yet, but it's working in Sigil.